# Analogue of j-invariant for CM fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, complex-multiplication

For any imaginary quadratic field $F$, the Hilbert class field $H$ is generated by the $j$-invariant of any elliptic curve with complex multiplication (CM) by $\mathcal O$, the ring of algebraic integers of $F$.

What is the simplest generalization of this well known and useful fact? Since an imaginary quadratic field is the simplest example of a CM field, one is led to ask:

Is there an (albeit conjectural) invariant of abelian surfaces which generates the Hilbert class field of a CM field $K$ (of degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$)?

Note that $K$ is a totally imaginary quadratic extension of a real quadratic field.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_twelfth_problem

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: [Ovseevič, A. I.
Abelian extensions of fields of CM type. 
Funkcional. Anal. i Priložen. 8 (1974), no. 1, 16–24.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02028302)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest generalisation to abelian surfaces is, I believe, the statement (which is a theorem, not a conjecture) that the [Igusa invariants](http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/g2c.igusa_invariants) of an abelian surface with CM by $K$ generate an abelian unramified extension of the reflex field of $K$. Note that the reflex field is not, in general, equal to $K$, and that there is no claim that the full Hilbert class field is obtained in this way. There is also a generalisation of this to higher dimensional principally polarised abelian varieties.

Comment: thanks! could you please point to a reference? also, are there interesting cases where the reflex field is $K$?